# Как сравнить даты в MySQL

Tags: mysql, дата

Есть таблица, в которой, кроме всего прочего, два поля

```
activeFrom [date] DEFAULT NULL
activeTill [date] DEFAULT NULL
```

Данные заносятся в таблицу из разных источников, поэтому в полях бывают разные значения: `NULL`, `0000-00-00` и  какая-то дата (например) `2015-12-16`.

**Задача**:
SQL запросом вытащить все строки, где текущая дата попадает между `activeFrom` и `activeTill`.
При этом, если в поле `NULL` или `0000-00-00`, считать как `true`. (т.е. если сейчас 2015-12-16, в таблице `activeFrom = NULL` и `activeTill = '2016-01-01'`, то запись нужна).
`activeTill` - дата включительно

---

В принципе я сделал, сравнивая все варианты.

```
SELECT * FROM [table] 
WHERE (
    (activeFrom='0000-0-0' AND activeTill='0000-0-0') OR
    (activeFrom<>'0000-0-0' AND activeTill<>'0000-0-0' AND NOW() BETWEEN activeFrom AND CONCAT(activeTill, ' 23:59:59')) OR
    (activeFrom='0000-0-0' AND activeTill<>'0000-0-0' AND NOW()<CONCAT(activeTill, ' 23:59:59') OR
    (activeFrom<>'0000-0-0' AND activeTill='0000-0-0' AND activeFrom<NOW()))
)
```

Но у меня есть подозрение, что можно решить как-то изящней. Без этого кошмарного перечисления.

Может кто-то предложить варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
  from table
 where curdate() between (if(ifnull(activeFrom,'0000-00-0')='0000-00-0',curdate(),activeFrom))
                     and (if(ifnull(activeTill,'0000-00-0')='0000-00-0',now(),activeTill))
```

Comment: Любопытно... Проверю

Comment: Работает, как надо. Спасибо. Принято... :)